# Publishing a video from blog to youtube

Tags: plugins, facebook, youtube

Is there any plugin for publishing a video from wordpress blog to youtube?

I have a wordpress blog and user will upload videos from wp admin and these videos should be published to youtube or facebook or any social network sites.

I know that reversing youtube->wordpress is very easy to do. But users must need to upload videos in my wordpress blog, so instead of uploading videos again into youtube I want to have one link that is "Publish to Youtube" or "Publish to facebook" then all videos will be available to public in youtube or facebook.

I know that there is **YouTubeVideoApp** using Zend frame work. I am looking for this same app in wordpress.

please any suggestions to achieve this? Thanks..

Comment: Any progress on this question? It shows no research and no progress...

Answer (score 1):

If there's a plugin, it has to be found.

If not, a custom solution has to be written.

But YouTube *does provide* an [API for that](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_direct_uploading).

> **YouTube API v2.0 – Direct Uploading**
>
> This page explains how to upload videos to YouTube using direct
>   uploading. Direct uploading lets you add videos that are in your video
>   library to YouTube. You should choose a direct-upload implementation
>   if you want to host or store videos uploaded through your site and
>   also add those videos to YouTube. In a direct-uploading scenario, when
>   a user uploads a video through your site, the video will be sent to
>   your servers. Your application will subsequently send an API request
>   to upload the video from your server to YouTube.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just get the user to upload the video to youtube then ue something like http://tubepress.org/ to display the videos? It's a simple to use plugin and the user will just need to paste the video URL in to a post, the plugin with do the rest of the embedding.

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off reversing this so youtube->wordpress rather than wordpress->youtube, embedding youtube videos in WordPress is extremely easy, WordPress will automatically find youtube URLs in your page and turn them into videos (if they are not hyperlinks)